# Global styles from App.xaml applying in designer but not at runtime as of recently

Tags: c#, wpf, app.xaml

**Problem**

I am working on an application, and recently I reorganized the file structure as I was adding more parts. Around this time I noticed that at runtime, styles from my App.xaml weren't getting applied. I made a lot of code changes at once before building so I am unsure of what may have changed.

**Information**

App.xaml remained unchanged before it stopped getting applied.

My program is laid out to have a main `<ContentControl>` that I bind some views to for some MVVM action. Originally I had all my views for different subfunctions of my program in one Views folder, but individual parts were getting too large so I split them up from this:

```
<Project>/Models
<Project>/ViewModels
<Project>/Views
```

to

```
<Project>/EventEditor/Models
<Project>/EventEditor/ViewModels
<Project>/EventEditor/Views
<Project>/ConfigurationEditor/Models
<Project>/ConfigurationEditor/ViewModels
<Project>/ConfigurationEditor/Views
```

My UserControl doesn't have any resources or styles of its own and should only be using the ones from App.xaml for now.

I only have 1 App.xaml file and no other files containing styles/dictionaries/etc outside of the individual view XAMLs.

Here is my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="EventSuite.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EventSuite"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Global Styles -->
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Steps Taken**

1. Clean build/rebuild
2. Breaking and using Tree Visualizer to investigate (no luck there)
3. Diffing files/projects. Nothing that I found could be causing this (I don't know exactly what to be looking for)

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to debug styles which are being used? I tried the WPF Tree Visualizer and it showed `null` for Style on my buttons, which is what I would expect since I didn't explicitly set any style.
2. Could file structure have a role to play? Perhaps App.xaml isn't being read correctly, or it's not being applied correctly. I haven't seen any warnings or indications of failure.
3. Namespace related? I would hope not...

In summary I am a little lost as to why App.xaml applies in design time and not at runtime. Why could this be happening after some changes to my project. I am lost! Let me know if you need more information or examples.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was an issue with App.xaml StartupURI.

My StartupURI was `MainWindow.xaml` and my App.xaml.cs was as follows:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var dialog = new SageCenter.View.MainWindow();
        dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

It was never calling `InitializeComponent()` on my application, but my window was still getting created. I kept the StartupURI in my App.xaml and changed App.xaml.cs to this to fix it:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The `StartupURI="MainWindow.xaml"` causes the `InitializeComponent()` call to instantiate my window.

Comment: This answered saved me hours. Thank you.  We had set up our WPF for dependency injection w/ services and the code in the App ctor no longer had the InitializeComponent(). Adding it at the bottom of the ctor resolved the issue.